# Not calculating exponential and log functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, exponent

I am having some challenges with exponential and log functions in Oracle in that I am not getting the expected answer to the formula below -I should be getting 10.97 bur rather I am getting 32.77

The formula is given as
M = exp(-8.758548 + 2.151173· ln(height) - 0.027927·ln (age) + Mspline)

Any assistance much appreciated -Code is as follows-

```
with samp as (select 1 as ID,178 as ht,30 as age, 0.101788 as MSPLINE
from dual)
select 
exp(-7.664278+2.151173*ln(samp.ht)-0.027927*ln(samp.age)+Mspline) from samp;
```

Comment: You must have copied the number "-8.758548" wrong; instead you have "-7.664278". The former number gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, odd-why thank you -that helps immensely. and now works